# Java Mqtt SSL implementation

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, mqtt

I have to implement SSL connection in java

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

properties.setProperty(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.KEYSTORE, "C:\\Users\\SathishKumar\\cert.p12");
properties.setProperty(SSLSocketFactoryFactory.KEYSTOREPWD, "machchar001");
MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
options.setCleanSession(false);
options.setConnectionTimeout(10);
options.setSSLProperties(properties);
client.connect(options);`
```

I'm facing

```
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: The error implies you are using a private CA for the broker certificate so you will need to add a TrustStore with the CA cert

Comment: could you tell me how to do that

Comment: `https://www.emqx.com/en/blog/how-to-use-mqtt-in-java`, **Connecting with TLS/SSL** , `String caFilePath = "/cacert.pem";` , `String clientCrtFilePath = "/client.pem";`, `String clientKeyFilePath = "/client.key";`, and more....